# How to vertically align the following equations?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align, alignment

Consider the following  screenshot. I want to vertically align the left `=` as shown in the *expected* part.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align*}
    a_1=4   &= 4 + 3 \times 0 \\
    a_2=7   &= 4 + 3 \times 1 \\
    a_3=10  &= 4 + 3 \times 2 \\
    a_4=13  &= 4 + 3 \times 3 \\
    a_5=16  &= 4 + 3 \times 4 \\
    a_6=19  &= 4 + 3 \times 5 \\
    a_7=22  &= 4 + 3 \times 6 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `alignat` or `array`.

The first solution has already been proposed; I use `{}` after every `&=` for uniformity, even if just one would suffice.

Using `array` spares this and the result is the same. On the other hand, `array` would be much easier if you also need other alignment points, say to go up to *a*<sub>11</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
% R    L      R   L
  a_1 &={} &  4  &= 4 + 3 \times 0 \\
  a_2 &={} &  7  &= 4 + 3 \times 1 \\
  a_3 &={} & 10  &= 4 + 3 \times 2 \\
  a_4 &={} & 13  &= 4 + 3 \times 3 \\
  a_5 &={} & 16  &= 4 + 3 \times 4 \\
  a_6 &={} & 19  &= 4 + 3 \times 5 \\
  a_7 &={} & 22  &= 4 + 3 \times 6 
\end{alignat*}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{@{} l >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}l @{}}
  a_1 &= &  4  &= 4 + 3 \times 0 \\
  a_2 &= &  7  &= 4 + 3 \times 1 \\
  a_3 &= & 10  &= 4 + 3 \times 2 \\
  a_4 &= & 13  &= 4 + 3 \times 3 \\
  a_5 &= & 16  &= 4 + 3 \times 4 \\
  a_6 &= & 19  &= 4 + 3 \times 5 \\
  a_7 &= & 22  &= 4 + 3 \times 6 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{@{} l >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}l @{}}
  a_1    &= &  4  &= 4 + 3 \times 0 \\
  a_2    &= &  7  &= 4 + 3 \times 1 \\
  a_3    &= & 10  &= 4 + 3 \times 2 \\
  a_4    &= & 13  &= 4 + 3 \times 3 \\
  a_5    &= & 16  &= 4 + 3 \times 4 \\
  a_6    &= & 19  &= 4 + 3 \times 5 \\
  a_7    &= & 22  &= 4 + 3 \times 6 \\
  a_{11} &= & 34  &= 4 + 3 \times 10
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align*}
    a_1&=\phantom{0}4   = 4 + 3 \times 0 \\
    a_2&=\phantom{0}7   = 4 + 3 \times 1 \\
    a_3&=10  = 4 + 3 \times 2 \\
    a_4&=13  = 4 + 3 \times 3 \\
    a_5&=16  = 4 + 3 \times 4 \\
    a_6&=19  = 4 + 3 \times 5 \\
    a_7&=22  = 4 + 3 \times 6 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `alignat`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    a_1 & =&4 &= 4 + 3 \times 0 \\
    a_2 & = & 7&= 4 + 3 \times 1 \\
    a_3 & ={}&10 &= 4 + 3 \times 2 \\
    a_4 & = &13 &= 4 + 3 \times 3 \\
    a_5 & = &16 &= 4 + 3 \times 4 \\
    a_6 & = &19 &= 4 + 3 \times 5 \\
    a_7 & = &22 &= 4 + 3 \times 6
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]