# How can I align these equations?

Tags: math-mode, align, alignment, alignat, tabulary

Consider the following two equations:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\log(RT_{LKPijk}) &= &b_{0} + b_{1}x_{1i} + b_{2}x_{2i} + b_{3}x_{3i} + b_{5}x_{5i} + u_{ij} + w_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk} \tag{1}\\
&\log(RT_{DCMPijk}) &= min[&b_{0} + b_{1}x_{1i} + b_{2}x_{2i} + b_{3}x_{3i} + b_{6}x_{6i} + u_{ij} + w_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk}, \tag{2}\\
&&&b_{0} + b_{1}x_{1i} + b_{2}x_{2i} + b_{3}x_{3i} + b_{5}x_{5i} + \Delta p + u_{ij} + w_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk}]
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

I would like to align the `log=`-parts, the is equal symbols and the `b_{1}`. This is the best I achieved so far. But I cannot get it done. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: How can I compile TeX-Code on tex.stackexchange?

[image]

Comment: Write on Stack a compilable tex code that starts with **\documentclass[...]{...} packages... begin{document} ... your code ... end{document}**, please, thank you.

Comment: Try with this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat)

Comment: Off-topic: You shoud to use `\min` instead of min.

Comment: Try also with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582213/how-to-vertically-align-the-following-equations?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX! You must remember that 3 alignment points requires 5 ampersands: 1 for each alignment point, and 1 to introduce each column but the first. Also, your lines are a bit too long for the default layout, and I had to load `geometry` to have more decent margins. Last points: 10 pt is the default font size, and it is simpler to use  `alignat` and `\notag` for the last line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
&\log(RT_{LKPijk}) & &= &b_{0} &+ b_{1}x_{1i} + b_{2}x_{2i} + b_{3}x_{3i} + b_{5}x_{5i} + u_{ij} + w_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk} \\[1ex]
&\log(RT_{DCMPijk}) & &= \min[&b_{0} & + b_{1}x_{1i} + b_{2}x_{2i} + b_{3}x_{3i} + b_{6}x_{6i} + u_{ij} + w_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk}, \\
&&& & b_{0} & + b_{1}x_{1i} + b_{2}x_{2i} + b_{3}x_{3i} + b_{5}x_{5i} + \Delta p + u_{ij} + w_{ik} + \epsilon_{ijk}] \notag
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!